# How do I get Windows Desktop Search to index my Exchange mailbox after installing Outlook 2010?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2010, windows-desktop-search

Prior to upgrading to Outlook 2010, I'd been using Windows Desktop Search (WDS) to index my Exchange Mailbox (which doesn't operate in cached mode) quite happily.

However, since upgrading to Outlook 2010, I am no longer able to get search results for mail items, which was my main reason for having it installed (Outlook's own search is way too slow).

Is it possible to re-enable this functionality, either through a plug-in or registry tweak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Changes in Outlook 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179110.aspx) :

> **Search Toolbar add-in**
>
> The Search Toolbar add-in setup code
>   is removed in Outlook 2010. The Search
>   Toolbar add-in enables local indexing
>   of online mode Exchange Server mailbox
>   stores by using Windows Desktop
>   Search. As a result of this change,
>   e-mail in online Exchange mailboxes
>   will not appear in the results of
>   Windows Explorer searches. The online
>   indexing add-in is a legacy component
>   that adversely affects performance of
>   Outlook during startup and shutdown.
>   With this removed in Outlook 2010,
>   users will experience improved Outlook
>   reliability and significantly lower
>   Exchange bandwidth usage. For fast
>   search, use Cached Exchange Mode or
>   for online mode, use Exchange Search
>   in Exchange 2007 and later versions.

Translation: You don't.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the case, but couldn't find anything definitive